# Is a 17 inch frame 26 inch wheels Giant Boulder Bike too small for someone who’s 5’11-6’0?

Tags: size

So I wanted to get a bike and came across a Giant Boulder Bike. It has 26 inch wheels and 17 inch frame. I’m 5’11 or 6’0. Is this bike to small for me? If so, what size would be good?

Answer (score 1):

Normal advice is to test ride the bike to see. 17" is a medium frame, and likely to be on the small side for someone over 5'10". If you cannot test ride the bike, presume the frame is too small.

For reference I am 5' 10", and ride a medium, but a large frame also fits me fairly well. I choose medium as I ride technical single track, and do lots of rides of only 1-2 hours long. For less technical and longer rides, a large frame suits me better.

Do note that body geometry and flexibly can dictate a size up or down for a particular manufacturer, so a size that suits one person might not be a good fit for someone of the same height.

Comment: I'm 5'10" with long legs and a bad shoulder, so I tend to go towards "large" frames to help keep the front wheel further in front of me. "Large" for me is ~470 mm reach with an effective top tube length of ~630 mm. With smaller wheels, I'd lean into my bias towards longer frames/wheelbases